# Recieve an image file using ajax from a direct url to an image file

Tags: jquery, ajax, image

Imagine I want to get the image from:

http://www.entheosweb.com/fireworks/images/tracing/img18.jpg

using jquery ajax.

How do I go about doing that.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.entheosweb.com/fireworks/images/tracing/img18.jpg',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "image",
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
        data = data.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
        data = data.replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
        $('#file_content').html('<pre>' + data + '</pre>');    
    },
    error: function(a,b,c){
        alert("There has been an error! Try again...");
    } 
});
```

Something along these lines I guess?

Comment: Why do you want to do this ? You can just use the image link to display the image in html.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: I guess he wants to display the file content as plain text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need ajax for that, with javascript, you can simply set the SRC property value.

```
$(function(){
   $("#img1").attr(
      "src","http://www.entheosweb.com/fireworks/images/tracing/img18.jpg") 

});​
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/PBKpk/1/

Comment: BWHAHAHAHAHAHHAHAHAHAHAHAHHAHA. *sighs*. It has been a long day. I really apologise for wasting your time.